# my app have problem use plugin inappwebview after i get url download my app force. can anyone can help me?

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, flutter-inappwebview

Container(
child: Column(children: [
Expanded(
child: InAppWebView(
initialUrl: selectedUrl,
initialHeaders: {},
initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
debuggingEnabled: true, useOnDownloadStart: true),
),
onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
webView = controller;
},
onLoadStart:
(InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {},
onLoadStop:
(InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {},
onDownloadStart: (controller, url) async {
print("onDownloadStart $url");
final taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
url: url,
savedDir: (await getExternalStorageDirectory()).path,
headers: {},
showNotification:
true,
openFileFromNotification:
true,
);
},
))
]))

Answer (score 0):

have you added the required permissions? if not, try adding these permissions to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```